# Set cell values in two different sheets upon action in third sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for your help in advance. New to scripting. Trying to set values to true in two sheets that correspond to a value in a row from a source sheet.

Example: Sheet 1 gets a row added, corresponding Sheets 2 and 3 get a column set to true.

I do not have a script example to display

Answer (score 0):

#### ADD ROW set two columns to "TRUE"

When user adds a row to Sheet0 the next row in Sheets 2 and Sheet3 and column one get set to "TRUE"

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    let sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    if (sh2.getLastRow()) {
      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue("TRUE");
    } else {
      sh2.getRange(1,1).setValue("TRUE");
    }
    let sh3 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet3')
    if (sh3.getLastRow()) {
      sh3.getRange(sh3.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue("TRUE");
    } else {
      sh3.getRange(1,1).setValue("TRUE")
    }
  }
}
```

You can goto to [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and using the search box find any function that you don't understand. If it's a pure JavaScript function then go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can the Sheet 2 and 3 row be changed, regardless of row? Also, the row should match Sheet 1. Example: Sheets 2 and 3 correspond(match) to a value from Sheet 1 row.        Does this help?  = sheet1.getRange('A:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);

Comment: Anything can be changed.  But arriving at what you want requires that you articulate the requirements a little more clearly.  A script of your own design and some images may help.